# Tilde on unix:hpux and / or solaris

Tags: command-line, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

On Linux press F9 return a correct

```
~
```

On unix(solaris or hpux) return

```
0~
```

How to set correct tilde on those systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found
first must press

```
CTRL+V and key
```

in my case is F9
so i did

```
CTRL+V F9
```

and return this

```
^[[20~
```

Now i know is key 20 and i bind it to tilde

```
bind '"\e[20~":"~"'
```

I try if work pressing F9 and return tilde
I put this in $HOME/.profile for permanent change

Answer (score 2):

Function keys can be interpreted by the window manager or terminal emulator (you'll find that F11, for example, will usually maximize the window) or passed through to the program as VTxxx or ANSI escape sequences.

F9 on Linux and Solaris usually sends <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>~</kbd>. Depending on the versions of the software, `bash` or `ksh` will interpret this as either `0~` or `~`. On the other hand, if your shell is dash, which doesn't do any line editing, you'll see `^[[20~`.

To make F9 send `~`:

If you're using X (tested on a US layout keyboard):

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 75 = asciitilde"
```

On a Linux console, run `showkey` to find F9's keycode. On my system, it's 67.
Then run this (you may need to be root):

```
echo "keycode 67 = asciitilde" | loadkeys
```

On a Solaris 10 console, run `showkeys | more` to find F9's keytable entry. On my virtual machine with virtual USB keyboard, it's `key 66 all tf(9)`. Then create a file with these contents:

```
key 66 all ~
```

and run `loadkeys /path/to/file`.

Comment: xmodmap works fine but with X only,of course,for a pure cli environement what is the right command?

Comment: @elbarna I added how to do it on a Linux console. Other operating systems may differ. It may be impossible to change what function keys send if you're using a serial terminal. What environment are you using?

Comment: Hpux,aix and solaris.

Comment: @elbarna More specifically, what systems do you use where the keyboard you type on is not translated by an X server?

Comment: Atm solaris,i try loadkeys but no success

Comment: @elbarna Added solution for Solaris 10.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what makes you think F9 returning a tilde is "correct", but if you want a tilde, you should use the tilde key.

Function keys are mostly undefined, based on the differences in the client-side hardware you are using, the client-side software you are using, the server-side software you are using, and the server-side hardware you are using.